# Simple component doesnt appear on the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im trying to render on the browser my react component Numbers in **{getBetNumbers()}**

I get this error:

[image]

```
const newBet: React.FC = () => {
        
      const getBetNumbers = () => {
        while (++i <= 25) {
          if (i >= 100) {
            <Numbers>{i}</Numbers>;
          } else {
            <Numbers>{i}</Numbers>;
          }
        }
      };
      return (
            <NumbersContainer>{getBetNumbers()}</NumbersContainer>
    )
```

Comment: what you wanna show? you should setState the return value. and display that value in return JSX

Comment: I just want to show multiple numbers using a looping

Comment: Your method getBetNumbers() isn’t returning anything. You could push <Numbers>{i}</Numbers> to an array and return it. Then you could use the spread operator (…) right before calling the method like <NumbersContainer>{…getBetNumbers()}</NumbersContainer>

Answer (score 2):

Well you didn't call the function that returns JSX. Try this:

```
<NumbersContainer>{getBetNumbers()}</NumbersContainer>
```

Also, remove the curly braces of the function body, for an implicit `return`.

Comment: I did the changes but now im getting an error on the "newBet" in the first line probably a typescript error

Comment: Remove the `return` inside the JSX because it might return `undefined`

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood. Now i did the changes, im getting an error on the HTML call, {getBetNumbers()}